# slowing down and looping portions of songs on spotify

Tags: spotify

I use Spotify for all my music needs and was wondering if there was some way to write an app that would allow me to access the music from Spotify and slow songs down and loop portions of the songs. I am a musician, and something like this would help with practicing.

If it can be done, a brief outline of what I'd need to do would be appreciated.

Separately, would this be legal?

Comment: Great question, and glad you added your use case.  Please join in and vote at https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/Music-Looping-individual-Songs-or-Parts/idi-p/1551156 where the Spotify feature to repeat a section of a track has been requested (albeit without the smart slow down option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to write that application yourself using libspotify. However, I'm fairly certain the Terms of Service for libspotify disallow modifying the audio. I'm not sure if slowing down counts as "modifying" - that's probably a question for a lawyer.

Comment: Do I have to request a key to get access to the library?

Comment: Yes. You can do it on Spotify's Developer Website, and it's an instant process (no human intervention).

Answer (score 1):

@iKenndac is correct, but I just wanted to add that modifying the PCM stream given by libspotify is technically against the legal terms & conditions. However, if you do not redistribute such an application (ie, personal and private use only), you'd not be in any legal trouble.

(Disclaimer: I work for Spotify, but am not a lawyer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Djay for this. Djay have a function so you can play your songs in spotify at slower speed, or faster speed.The function is called key lock/ time stretching and it seems to work on mac running on OSX 10.9 or higher, iphone 4s or better, ipad 2 or nexus devices. Hopefully it will work for more devices soon. It is not the cheapest app in the world but it should work.

Here is a link to the ipad version.

[djay 2 - algoriddim GmbH](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/djay-2/id669196929?mt=8&uo=4&at=1l3vuyx)

iphone

[djay 2 for iPhone - algoriddim GmbH](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/djay-2-for-iphone/id669198374?mt=8&uo=4&at=1l3vuyx)

and mac

[djay Pro - algoriddim GmbH](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/djay-pro/id947578651?mt=12&uo=4&at=1l3vuyx)